# How to split php cronjob into parts

Tags: php

There is a PHP script. It gets data from external API and import(update/delete) data into WordPress database (products for Woocommerce). There are a lot of products... To import all of them the script needs about 2-3 hours.

The problem is that when the script executes, the memory is not cleaned which leads to its overflow. After that, the script just silently dies without any error.

In short, the script looks like this:

```
$products = getProductsFromApi();
foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    $this->import($product);
}
```

The idea is to split the cronjob script into parts: if `$currentMemory > 100Mb` then stop the script and run it again but not from the beginning, from the moment it stopped.

How can this be realized? If there is a restriction on a server: only 1 cronjob script per 2 hours.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Reduce what `getProductsFromApi` returns and then do it in batches.

Comment: Is it possible to get only the changed products from the API? If there is a modified timestamp or something, you could use it to filter only the products that have been updated since the last run.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone even if I reduce `$products` arrays, the memory will be overloaded anyway since it's not released during execution one script.

Comment: I had actually built something along these lines a couple years ago... because it had to reconcile a few hundred million records a night into a stupid metrics export file format for a moron who no longer works for the company. Oops, sorry, too much bitterness there ;) But in the end, I killed the script. However it used a self-propogating exec() command that would spawn a new sub process leaving off where it was, and kills itself. All run from a cron. Gosh, the code is about a thousand lines... too much to add here.

Comment: I need sleep ... kept posting this comment in the wrong place lol : Out of curiosity, @ZhiV , but how BIG is the initial import from the external API?

Comment: @IncredibleHat around 20000 elements with pictures which I need to save on a server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tool such as [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) to create a queue and workers for importing processes. You can program each worker to process a certain amount of products that would take time less than the server's maximum execution time.

Gearman will also allow you to control how many workers can run simultaneously. Therefore, the importing process would be faster and you'll make sure the server resources aren't being totally consumed by workers.

Answer (score 2):

You can serilize the $products array when $currentMemory > 100Mb to a file and then execute the script again:

```
$limit = 100*1000*1000;
$store  = 'products.bin';
$products = [];

if ( !file_exists($store)) {
    $products = getProductsFromApi();    
} else {
    $products = unserialize(file_get_contents($store));
}

foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    $this->import($product);
    unset($products[$key]);
    if (memory_get_usage() > $limit) {
        file_put_contents($store,serialize($products));
        exec('nohup /usr/bin/php -f myscript.php');
        exit(1);
    }    
}
unlink ($store);
```

Comment: And I need to run only one cronjob? (sorry, I've not figured out how cronjob works yet)

Comment: @IncredibleHat around 20000 elements with pictures which I need to save on a server.

Comment: Ok, then that should be fine to serialize to a file to continue with. I was worried it was like a few million and so large the file put would crash itself.

Comment: yeah, but I should to use WP functions =(

Comment: @napuzba, btw, `exit(1)` is redundant here cuz after the second overflow script will die.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sleep function

For example

```
  $products = getProductsFromApi();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    // you can use your condition here instead of this 
    if($i%10==0){// run ten times then sleep for 100 second    
sleep(100);
    }
        $this->import($product);
    $i++;
    }
```

https://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: Heh... no. Read his question a bit closer ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat I will :)

Comment: `sleep()`  is useless in this situation ))

Comment: @IncredibleHat   This is a good question let's search about it :)